# How can I find out cost per instance per month on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have some instances and each instance belongs to a different client. I want to know how much each instance is costing me on a monthly basis?
I called the AWS but not success yet

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [AWS Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/de/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/) . There you can group your costs by instance.

Answer (score 5):

The closest solution to what you want is going to be using [cost allocation tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html). By tagging the resources correctly, i.e. using a tag of `Client` you are able to identify in a billing breakdown how much a clients resources have costed per each service.

Once you have configured these you can generate your bill based on tags, additionally you can either use the console or CLI to find this detail using [cost explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/) and grouping by tags.

This will be advantageous over a logical resource anyway as it will persist past the resources lifetime, i.e. if that instance is terminated you will still know the total spend by the client.

Answer (score 4):

Tags is probably the quickest way, but maybe the preferred way is to setup each client in a separate AWS account, and have a parent account and turn on/use consolidated billing.

Not only will this make the billing/chargebacks cleaner, if you and a client ever need to part ways, you can transfer their entire account with all of their data/instances/databases back to them.